# radio inputs not working correctly in angular 7

Tags: html, angular

I got radio inputs, rendered using the structural directive ngFor.

```
    <form>
      <label *ngFor="let user of staffMembers" class="stuff" for="user.username"> 
          {{user.username}}
          <input type="radio" [name]="user.username" [value]="user.username"> 
      </label>
    </form>
```

I got the inputs correctly but i can check multiple fields like checkbox. It's not the default behavior for radio inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name shouldn't be unique to get the normal behavior, otherwise, it's just radio with only one possibility.

```
<input type="radio" name="user" [value]="user.username">
```

Comment: "The name should be unique" could be confusing. In the original code, the names are unique, and that is the problem.

Comment: Yep, fixed it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Because you are creating a new radio group with each line, not a new radio option. The input [name] is the name of the radio group, NOT the option.

```
 <form>
  <label *ngFor="let user of staffMembers" class="stuff" for="staffMembers1"> 
      {{user.username}}
      <input type="radio" id="staffMembers1" name="staffMembers" [value]="user.username"> 
  </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give all radio inputs the same name:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Right now it seems each radio input gets a different one since user.username is always different.